# No command 'bee' found

Tags: go, beego

I am trying to run a project that uses beego framework. When I try to run the project I encounter the following problem every time.

```
No command 'bee' found, did you mean:
 Command 'bel' from package 'belier' (universe)
 Command 'bbe' from package 'bbe' (universe)
 Command 'pee' from package 'moreutils' (universe)
 Command 'beep' from package 'beep' (universe)
 Command 'ree' from package 'ree' (universe)
 Command 'beet' from package 'beets' (universe)
 Command 'ben' from package 'ben' (universe)
 Command 'beer' from package 'gerstensaft' (universe)
 Command 'be' from package 'bugs-everywhere' (universe)
 Command 'see' from package 'mime-support' (main)
 Command 'tee' from package 'coreutils' (main)
 Command 'btee' from package 'ruby-bcat' (universe)
 Command 'beef' from package 'beef' (universe)
bee: command not found
```

My Go Environment : ($ go env)

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/MYNAME/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build235821315=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
```

My Environment declerations in bash_profile :

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
export GOPATH=$HOME/work
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:$GOPATH/bin
export PATH="$GOPATH/bin:$PATH"'
```

Where am i doing wrong? What should i do?

Comment: The go path in your bash profile is not taking effect as you can see. `go env` reports a different `GOPATH` than what is exported in your bash_profile. Given that it's possible the `PATH` changes (some of which are duplicated - you add `$GOPATH/bin` twice) are also not taking effect.

Answer (score 2):

As [**bee**](https://beego.me/docs/install/bee.md) is not available by default in Go, you have to install it first using `go get` command or copying it manually to `$GOPATH/src` or `$GOPATH`, as follows:

```
 go get github.com/beego/bee
```

Comment: I did it at first:)